# Why are colloidal sol particles of acidic dyes negatively charged and basic dyes positively charged, when it should be the other way round?

Tags: acid-base, ph, colloids, dye

From *NCERT Class 12 Chemistry*; Sri Aurobindo Marg, New Delhi, India; January **2019**; p. 136:

> Colloidal solutions of basic dyes like methylene blue are positively charged whereas colloidal solutions of acid dye stuffs (eosin and Congo red) are negatively charged.
>
> The charge on the sol particles is due to one or more reasons, due to preferential adsorption of common ions from solution and/or due to formulation of electrical double layer.

A base releases $\ce{OH-}$ ions, so it should preferably adsorb the same ions from water and become negatively charged. Why do basic dyes become positively charged then?

Similarly, acidic dyes release $\ce{H+}$ ions, so they should become positively charged, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Bases rather capture H+(aq), as the Broensted-Lawry definition is wider than the Arrhenius one. E.g. NH3 does not release OH-. OH- is created indirectly by water autodissociation when H+(aq) is being depleted, forming NH4+(aq).